# Android Studio Hello World Project not Displayed on Design XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio and I started a new project. By default, I was given the Hello World app.

When running on the emulator, the text is displayed. However, on the XML design page, no text is displayed. Am I missing an SDK or anything like that?

Comment: please share your XML code.

Comment: I think you don't understand your `XML`

Comment: @skpanchal Correct! i know some html but no other markup languages. Im mostly familiar with OOP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the minimum API selected in the preview window.. try selecting a lower min API..you XML preview will show..

It doesn't even show the "Hello World" in the preview when i started my first project,only displays 'Rendering problem' and 'Failed to instantiates one or more class'.This helps me out, try this..... in the left side menu, GoTo
base-> res-> values-> styles.xml

(browse in the project window of android studio, notice a small +sign before com.example.HelloWorld project then click on res + sign and then + sign on values, you will see a file called styles.xml, double click that file, it will open in the right pane, edit there....)

then write "Base." in the line
       `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`
just before the `Theme.AppCompat` like this

```
 <style name="AppTheme"     
        parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: I don't know any XML, and aside from a little HTML, I don't know any markup languages. Where do I put it in? Do I just write Base? <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>

Comment: glad to help.. happy coding... :-)

Answer (score 1):

After changing the style theme, I was able to see the text:
[image]